# Proof of recursive multiply algorithm correctness

Tags: algorithms, recursion, recursive-algorithms

I'm struggling with mathematical proof of this algorithm, which I have found in a textbook, but unfortunately there is no solution available. I have already proved it when c is >= z and have no idea how to continue.

Here is algorithm:

y and z are natural numbers, c is natural constant c>=2

```
function multiply(y,z)
    1. if z=0 then return(0) else
    2. return(multiply(cy,[z/c]) + y*(z mod c))
```

Comment: Since $z=c[z/c]+(z\mod{c})$, then $yz=y(c[z/c]+(z\mod{c}))=yc[z/c]+y(z\mod{c})=(cy)[z/c]+y(z\mod{c})$. Also $yz=0$, when $z=0$. The return value is then $yz$. So, if it returns, it returns the correct value. The other thing that you need for correctness is to show that it does return. For that note that, since $c\geq2$, then $|z|>|[z/c]|$. So, the second argument in the recursive call gets smaller and smaller and eventually zero. So, eventually the branch of the IF is reached and the recursion unfolds.

Comment: You say you've proved it when $c\ge m$, but $m$ doesn't appear elsewhere in the probem. I'm going to assume that $c$ is also an integer. It seems that you would like to prove that the algorithm is correct (i.e., that $yz = (cy)\lfloor z/c \rfloor + y(z \bmod c)$ and that it terminates. For correctness it might help to write $z = qc+r$ where $q = \lfloor z/c \rfloor$ and $r= z \bmod c$. Just do the calculation. For termination the standard approach is to use induction (on some parameter).

Comment: Sorry, about m, I meant z

Comment: @owl please rewrite your comment as solution so I can accept it